# Make big margins using bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I want to make **big margins** on my webpage. I also want the **margin to get smaller and smaller when I reduce the screen size**, until we hit the webpage's content. Then, Bootstrap should automatically take care of the responsiveness of the website.

I tried using `<body class="mx-5">"`, which is the biggest possible margin size (from 1 to 5). I looked up how to make bigger margins, but I didn't see anything relevant.

**NOTE:** I want the margin to *automatically* reduce themselves when we make the screen smaller.